# Article omission or not?

Tags: grammar, articles

> I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm often wrong when it comes to grammar. I usually go with my gut feeling.

I'm documenting some parts of an application and I was reminded that I often omit the *the* article in my sentences. So we started discussing individual cases but I was objecting to my very best knowledge why *the* should not be part of them but I'm not sure.

I would still like to write them correctly even though none of us are native speakers.

1. *The* donut chart is used ...

   I wrote it without the article because in my understanding *the* refers to noun *chart* which in this case is well defined by the word *donut* so I would say it doesn't need an article. And it's about a donut chart that is the only one on the component I'm documenting.
2. *The* chart slice sizes are ...

   I also omitted the article, but in the end I think my sentence was wrong, because article here refers to *slice sizes* and I should actually wrote it as *Chart's slice sizes* and of course without the article.
3. top part with *the* date period selector

   This is the whole text of some bullet point. I omitted the article because it refers to a specific selector. A *date period* selector specifically.

Etc... As said, this is all very fuzzy to me.

Comment: Can the *close* voter please tell me why this is off topic? It's a specific grammar question...

Comment: @Davo: I understand that with plurals they're optional but not in a sense that you may or may not use them. But rather when you use them they provide a different meaning. As I understand it, when they're omitted in plurals it means the whole set is meant, but when there would be an article *the* then it would mean a subset of the whole set. Is this correct thinking?

Comment: @Davo & Mitch: I didn't know there was an ELL site... Help page also doesn't state that and IMO it should. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using **["headlinese"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/headlinese)** for a specific purpose (as in a PowerPoint presentation, for example), then you would include the article; i.e.,

> "The donut chart is used" to show the relationships, etc.
>
> "The chart-slice sizes are" indicative of the relative importance, etc.
>
> "The top part with the date-period selector" enables you to, etc.

Comment: Note that except for the use of articles and a few needed commas, your English is excellent.

Comment: Ha ha... :) Thanks. I've been using it for a few decades now. The problem is I simply just use it (either verbally or writing it) but when I start thinking of its grammar correctness I get confused to the point that I loose my gut feeling with specific issues at hand.

Comment: That happens to us native speakers all the time as well. :-)